# Regarding calculating the bias of coin with uncertainty

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Suppose you have a coin that you flip $n$ times and the result have $m$ heads and $n-m$ tails. How accurate can you predict the bias of the coin to be $\frac m n$?

I know that $P\left[\text{head}>\frac{n}2 + k\sqrt{n}\right]$ < $e^{-k^2/2}$ where $k$ should be the real bias, but how would you set a bound in which you know just the experiment bias?

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: How much probability theory do you know? Do you know how to apply the central limit theorem to transform your binomial distribution into a normal distribution? Do you know what MLE is? Do you know how to perform statistics test? If yes, what have you done along these lines?

Comment: For large $m$, $n$ you can write down a fairly simple say $99\%$ confidence interval for the probability of head. It is not exactly what you wrote, but related.

Comment: I am in introductory discrete mathematics class, we just covered chebyshev the other day, this was a motivational question in the beginning of my textbook, but the textbook didn't provide an answer, hence the question

Comment: @AndréNicolas what if $n$ is 100, how would I find an inverse mapping for the bound of the approximation with certainty of probability $p$

Comment: As long as the coin is not too biased, we can use the normal mean $\frac{m}{100}$, variance $\frac{m}{100}\left(1-\frac{m}{100}  \right)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but how much certainty could I say that it is within the variance? I am trying to construct the bound using chebyshev using random variables, but I found that if I don't know the bias, I can't calculate the expectation ?

Comment: The only issue is estimating the variance. Once we have done the experiment, the expression I gave above lets us estimate the variance. Or else you can be pessimistic, worst case variance is $\frac{1}{100}(0.25)$.

Answer (score 2):

We give a simplified version of the answer, for $n$ large and bias not too extreme.

Suppose we want say a $95\%$ confidence interval for the mean. We do the coin tossing $n$ times, getting say $m$ heads. Then our estimate for the probability of heads is $\frac{m}{n}$.

Let random variable $X$ be the number of heads in $n$ tosses of a coin that has probability $p$ of landing heads. Then under our conditions $\frac{X}{n}$ is close to normal, mean $p$, variance $\frac{1}{n}p(1-p)$. We can use $\frac{m}{n}$ to estimate $p$ in the variance calculation. Or else we can note that $p(1-p)\le 0.25$ for all $p$ in the interval from $p==0$ to $p=1$.

Let's be pessimistic. Then a (for example) $95\%$ confidence interval for $p$ is the interval $$\left(\frac{m}{n}-\frac{1.96}{2\sqrt{n}}, \frac{m}{n}+\frac{1.96}{2\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

If there are questions about the procedure, please leave a message.